# ¿Cómo usar la ruta de /var/www/html en centOS 7?

Tags: apache, nginx, centos

Para mis desarrollos web quiero usar vagrant con la distribución de centOS 7 y usando el stack de LEMP, pero tengo dos problemas.

El primero de ellos es que en centOS 7 para lo web hay que usar la ruta de:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/
```

y como uso vagrant estoy redireccionando el contenido de esa ruta a mi carpeta htdocs que cree para hacer el enlace entre la máquina virtual y la carpeta de mi pc host, el problema es que no tengo los permisos y siempre me muestra el mensaje de **403 forbidden**.

Ahora el segundo problema es que si uso la ruta de:

```
/var/www/html
```

al poner en la url **localhost:8080** si muestra que nginx ésta funcionando bien, pero al querer cargar el index de mi proyecto me dice que no encuentra dicho archivo aunque esté bien ubicado...éste problema no me lo da con **ubuntu**, uso la misma ruta y funciona todo perfecto.

¿Como puedo arreglar esto usando centOS7?

Gracias.

Comment: Creo q la ruta en centos para el dominio por defecto estaba en /var/www/vhosts/default/httpdocs o similar.

Comment: De todos modos, quizá tengas que activar el FollowSymLynks para que siga los enlaces simbólicos (entiendo q has hecho ln -s para linkar la carpeta htdocs)

Comment: al permiso cambiale de dueño `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/nginx/html/ `en cuanto a que no encuentra el archivo verifica el virtualhost de apache generalmente esta `/etc/apache2/site-enabled/`

Comment: Sí se permiten preguntas sobre [gestión de servidores y redes de ordenadores](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/166/301). Por favor, votemos para no cerrar esta pregunta.

Comment: Buenas, comentamos si te valió la respuesta o necesitas más datos.

Answer (score 1):

Todo es relativo, porque depende de como lo tengas instalado y configurado puedes modificar los `VirtulaHost` para que su `DocumentRoot` sea otro, sin tener que hacer nada a nivel de `SymLink`.

Ten en cuenta también lo que comentas de los puertos, por defecto `nginx` usa el puerto `8080` pero puedes configurarlo para que escuche en el puerto 80 y sea él quien sirva la web como si fuera un `Apache`.

Del mismo modo que lo puedes configurar como proxy para `Apache`

Aquí te dejo un pequeño tutorial de [como crear un `Virtualost` en Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-on-centos-7)
¿Puedes poner tu archivo de configuración de `nginx`?

Ahí puedes ver como configurarlo y como crear un `VirtulaHost`, creo que te puede ser de ayuda para lo que comentas.

Si no te sirve, me dices y buscamos una alternativa. Ten en cuenta también la configuración de `PHP-FPM` para que pueda tener un pool de PHP para cada `VirtualHost`